# how can we upload any file/image using rest api robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, rest-assured

need to upload a file and here are the details which I am passing

headers

```
Content-Type=application/json
```

body is having form-data

```
vendor[file]="path of file"

${header}    Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/form-data   
${body}     Create Dictionary   vendor[file]=C:\\Api\\filepath

Put On Session   session    ${registration}   headers=${header}   files=${body}
```

I am getting 500 as a response on it but expected will be 200

Comment: you need learn more about **http**. suggest try using `curl` or `postman` to upload file first, then try `robot framework`.

Comment: FWIW, 500 is a server error. Have you checked to see if you've been given an error message?